# $V_0^1 f \geq \frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=1}^\infty V_0^1 f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \{0,\frac{1}{3^n}\}$, define $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$. Is there any clue to prove that $V_0^1 f \geq \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty V_0^1 f_n$? Here $V$ is the total variation.

Now I can only argue that when any of $f_n$ is not a function of bounded variation, the inequality holds. If each $f_n$ is of bounded variation, it may be beneficial to keep it in mind that $f_n$ can only have finite noncontinuous points in this case.

Moreover, from the accepted proof, we get a stronger conclusion:
$$
V_0^1 f \geq \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=1}^\infty V_0^1 f_n,
$$
which is tight since we can construct an example to make the equality hold.

Comment: What is the definition of $V_0^1f$? The variation?

Comment: It is the total variation on $[0,1]$ ;)

Comment: @Thomas I think I can only argue that when any of $f_n$ is not a function of bounded variation, the inequality holds. If each $f_n$ is of bounded variation, we can know that it can only have finite noncontinuous points in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality follows once we prove the following claim:

> **Claim.** For any $x, y \in [0, 1]$, we have
>   $$ |f(y) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_n(y) - f_n(x)|. $$

*Proof of Claim.* This is obvious when $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. So assume otherwise and let $N$ be the smallest $n$ for which $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| \neq 0$ holds. Then by the reverse triangle inequality, we have

\begin{align*}
|f(y) - f(x)|
&\geq |f_N(x) - f_N(y)| - \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} |f_n(y) - f_n(x)| \\
&\geq \frac{1}{3^N} - \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^N}.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, by the triangle inequality we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_n(y) - f_n(x)| \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^N}. $$

Combining these two inequalities gives

$$ |f(y) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^N} \geq \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_n(y) - f_n(x)|, $$

which proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you, this is an amazing solution!

Comment: @AndrewSong, You're welcome!

Comment: @AndrewSong, I think I fixed the error. Does it seem okay now?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again!